# How to prevent game controller button B from quitting app / navigating back to menu in tvOS

Tags: tvos, gamecontroller

The game controller button `B` is, by default, quitting the app and navigating back to the tvOS home screen. At first I thought this was intuitive, but quickly realized that's what the Nimbus MENU button (dead middle of the controller) is for, and that I actually want to use button `B` in-game.

Setting a change handler for button `B` works, but the app still quits when the button is released.

```
GCControllerButtonValueChangedHandler buttonBHandler = ^(GCControllerButtonInput *button, float value, BOOL pressed) {
        NSLog(@"B");
};
```

Comment: By "that's what the Nimbus MENU button is for" I mean, selecting Quit from an in-game menu presented by the game. This is what GCController's controllerPausedHandler is for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue.

The solution was to have my main ViewController inherit from GCEventViewController instead of UIViewController.

By default, when using GCEventViewController, the MENU button will not return to the menu. In this case, if you want it to be able to return to the menu with the original behavior you can simply set controllerUserInteractionEnabled to YES.

see the documentation for this class here :
https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/GameController/Reference/GCEventViewController_Ref/index.html

edit : apple dev forum helpep me fix this issue : https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/57926#57926

hope this helps,

Comment: Checking it out, thanks 

François, will report back with results!

Comment: Will accept this answer soon - apologies I honestly have not came back to this part of the impl. yet!

Comment: Thanks François. This works. BUT my new problems after having subclassed GCEventViewController is that MENU button is not behaving as expected (getting swallowed, by default); and, #if os( tvOS ) around the class signature is not compiling such that I can no longer share my View Controller across iOS and tvOS (using Swift; I know this works in Obj-c). Will file new questions for those =)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I'm even setting controllerUserInteractionEnabled to false explicitly on viewDidLoad but the MENU button still sends me back to the previous view controller :/

Answer (score 0):

I too had the issue, related to Unity, but I think this rather hacky solution can help.

Deriving from GCEventViewController one can override several methods, one of them is:

```
- (void)pressesBegan:(NSSet<UIPress *> *)presses withEvent:(UIPressesEvent *)event
```

returning or handling presses without calling super removes all calls to the internals.

Comment: Thanks. either way you need to subclass GCEventViewController, so I'm not sure this is better than just providing a buttonB handler (for B) and controllerPausedHandler (for MENU). This per Francois' answer.